# how to set UIPageViewController page control background color

Tags: swift2, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I have a page view controller which displays several images. And it has page control at the bottom created by the following code:`func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return numOfImages
    }
    func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return currentIndex
    }`
The background is black as the image shows, so I just want to know is there any way that I can set its background color to clear color? I know this questions have been asked by others, but none of those answers helped.[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWTh1.png)

Comment: This code ain't the problem i guess , can you show full code or other little relevant methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this code from a youtube tutorial, but I've forgot the link, feel free to tell me the video link so that I can give credits to him...anyway, here is the code:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        for view in self.view.subviews{
            if view is UIScrollView{
                view.frame =  UIScreen.main.bounds
            } else if view is UIPageControl{
                view.backgroundColor = .clear
            }
        }
    }
```

just put this code in the PageViewController file